# Dataframe count of columns matching value in another column in that row

Tags: dataframe

How to find the count of columns with same value as a specified column in the dataframe with large number of rows.

For instance, below df has

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(5, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df.index.name = 'id'

     A  B   C   D
id              
0   7   6   6   2
1   6   5   3   5
2   8   8   0   9
3   0   2   8   9
4   4   3   8   5


bc_cols = ['B', 'C']
df['max'] = df[bc_cols].max(axis=1)


    A   B   C   D   BC_max
id                  
0   7   6   6   2   6
1   6   5   3   5   5
2   8   8   0   9   8
3   0   2   8   9   8
4   4   3   8   5   8
```

For each row, we want to get the number of columns with the value matching the max. I was able to get to by doing this.

```
 df["freq"] = df[bc_cols].stack().groupby(by='id').apply(lambda g: g[g==g.max()].count())


    A   B   C   D   BC_max  BC_freq
id                      
0   7   6   6   2   6       2
1   6   5   3   5   5       1
2   8   8   0   9   8       1
3   0   2   8   9   8       1
4   4   3   8   5   8       1
```

But this is turning out to be very inefficient and slow. We need to do this on a fairly large dataframe with several hundred thousand rows so I am looking for an efficient way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have `BC_max` why not re-use it:

```py
def get_bc_freq(row):
  if (row.B == row.BC_max) and (row.C == row.BC_max):
    return 2
  elif (row.B == row.BC_max) or (row.C == row.BC_max):
    return 1
  return 0

df['freq'] = df.apply(lambda row: get_bc_freq(row), axis=1)
```

Or the prettier one-liner:

```py
df['freq'] = df.apply(lambda row: [row.B, row.C].count(row.BC_max), axis=1)
```

---

UPDATE - to make the columns you use more dynamic you could use list comprehension (not sure how much this helps with performance but...):

```py
cols_to_use = ['B', 'C']
df['freq'] = df.apply(lambda row: [row[x] for x in cols_to_use].count(row.BC_max), axis=1)
```

Comment: I was trying to use the already calculated max but I was running into hiccups on how to apply for multiple columns. For ex, Col B and C are two columns in this example but in our full df, there are hundreds of columns we need to match.  Is there a way to select a list of columns in the row?

For instance, in the onliner -

df['freq'] = df.apply(lambda row: [Multiple Columns].count(row.BC_max), axis=1)

Comment: sure thing - see my update which uses list comprehension to take care of potentially many columns

Comment: That is perfect!! Exactly what I was looking for.